# Injecting html - using slot or v-html?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

So here’s my case:

I’m creating a modal via:

```
<Modal id="modal">    
    <my-component></my-component>    
</Modal>
```

Now I want the content inside the modal to be dynamic, so I can put `<input>` or `<table>` or w/e. I’ve tried using slots (it works), but it isn’t really dynamic. I’m wondering if I missed something that would allow the slot to be a bit more dynamic.

Here’s how my modal is set up:

```
<div 
    :id="id"
    class="main" 
    ref="main" 
    @click="close_modal"
>
    <div ref="content" class="content" :style="{minHeight: height, minWidth: width}">
        <div ref="title" class="title" v-if="title">
            {{ title }}
            <hr/>
        </div>
        <div ref="body" class="body">
            <slot></slot>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think using slots is a good choice for this. With the introduction of `slot-scope` in 2.5, you basically get a reverse property capability where you can set defaults within the child component and access them within the parent. They are of course completely optional to use and you're free to place whatever content you like in the slots.

Here's an example component that would allow you to customize the header, body and footers as you see fit:

```
// MyModal.vue
<template>
  <my-modal>
    <slot name="header" :text="headerText"></slot>
    <slot name="body" :text="bodyText"></slot>
    <slot name="footer" :text="footerText"></slot>
  </my-modal>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        headerText: "This is the header",
        bodyText: "This is the body.",
        footerText: "This is the Footer."
      }
    }
  }
</script>

// SomeComponent.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <my-modal>
      <h1 slot="header" slot-scope="headerSlotScope">
        <p>{{ headerSlotScope.text }}</p>
      </h1>
      <div slot="body" slot-scope="bodySlotScope">
        <p>{{ bodySlotScope.text }}</p>
        <!-- Add a form -->
        <form>
          ...
        </form>
        <!-- or a table -->
        <table>
          ...
        </table>
        <!-- or an image -->
        <img src="..." />
      </div>
      <div slot="footer" slot-scope="footerSlotScope">
        <p>{{ footerSlotScope.text }}</p>
        <button>Cancel</button>
        <button>OK</button>
      </div>
    </my-modal>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import MyModal from './MyModal.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    MyModal
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Well, I may need to change up the content completely. So I'm using `input` now, but I have a button that will clear the content and output something else, say `<table>`. Any idea how to incorporate this into the slot? Another factor is I might want to have a global Modal so that I can just access it via its `id` maybe.

Comment: This allows you to change it any way you like, in fact. In `SomeComponent.vue` you don't have to use an `h1` for the header slot, it could be whatever you like, same goes for the rest of the slots. You can omit any default content too and the slot won't render at all. It's quite flexible.

Comment: Is it possible to use Vuex? In my React project, I'm assigning a store variable to a component, which then gets rendered in the Modal.

Comment: I don't think it's possible in the way you want it to work, [raw HTML](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML) is rendered with the `v-html` directive, which from your question title you know of. As far as I am aware, the problem is data bindings are not applied through `v-html`., so you wouldn't be able to use, for example, `v-model` on an input element rendered via the store variable.